# Spring boot 2.0 HttpSecurity auth doesn't work without sent Authorization header

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, jwt

I have this security settings in class `WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http
        .addFilterBefore(corsFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class)
        .csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
        .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()));
}
```

JWTAuthenticationFilter:

```
class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
{
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private Logger                logger = Logger.getLogger("JWTAuthenticationFilter");

    JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
    {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws AuthenticationException
    {
        String username = req.getParameter("username");
        logger.info("Login attempt with username: " + username);

        return authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, req.getParameter("password"), new ArrayList<>())
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(
        HttpServletRequest req,
        HttpServletResponse res,
        FilterChain chain,
        Authentication auth
    )
    {
        String token = Jwts
            .builder()
            .setSubject(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET)
            .compact();

        res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
    }
}
```

JWTAuthorizationFilter:

```
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter
{
    JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager)
    {
        super(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
        HttpServletRequest req,
        HttpServletResponse res,
        FilterChain chain
    ) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        String header = req.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX))
        {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
            return;
        }
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
        if (token != null)
        {
            String user = Jwts
                .parser()
                .setSigningKey(SECRET)
                .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                .getBody()
                .getSubject();
            if (user != null)
            {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

- When I send the Authorization: Bearer "correct token" header, it's working fine.
- When I send the Authorization: Bearer "expired token" header, I got the correct error message.
- But If I don't send the header it won't bock the API call and I got the response without error message.
- If I send the Auth header with random text instead of Bearer I got the response without error message.

What could wrong with it?

Comment: How is the `JWTAuthenticationFilter` implemented.

Comment: I updated the question with the code.

Comment: I don't see anything related to authentication with a token. So how can it even work? You are basically logging in with a username and password and then supply a token. You nowhere read the token in this filter? So where is your token being read and used for authentication?

Comment: Updated again with JWTAuthorizationFilter class, the problem could be somewhere here.

Comment: If I don't send the Authorization header the getAuthentication won't be triggered.

Comment: I added a SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null); for the "if (header == null || !header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX))" and it looks fine now.

Comment: The problem is you are extending the `BasicAuthenticationFilter` and break the default (good) behavior. I also don't get why it are 2 filters, shouldn't it be a single filter? If you really want 2 filters you should at least be extending the `AbstractPreAuthenticationFilter` and override the correct methods instead of overriding the main entry method.

Comment: I'm pretty new with spring, I was following a tutorial, as I see not the best tutorial, but now this part of the auth is clear for me, I will rethink it by your ideas. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert but you can try to add your filters at a specific location with

```
.addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

Let me know if something changes

Comment: JWTAuthenticationFilter has no second parameter, I can't add it.

Comment: the second param is for addFilter Before, maybe I messed up the parhentesis

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I didn't see. But it's still not working, I got the api response without any error.